# Append two matrices in R without losing dimnames

Tags: r, matrix, append

How can I append two matrices without losing the dimnames?

Set up some data:

```
m1 <- structure(c(35.3, 31.7, 25.9, 15.8), 
    .Dim = c(2L, 2L), 
    .Dimnames = structure(list(
     Treatment = c("no1", "yes1"), Loc = c("North", "South")),
    .Names = c("Treatment", "Loc")))
m2 <- structure(c(9.5, 9.6, 7.4, 4.0), 
    .Dim = c(2L, 2L), 
    .Dimnames = structure(list(
    Treatment = c("no2", "yes2"), Loc = c("North", "South")), 
    .Names = c("Treatment", "Loc")))
```

Which gives:

```
> m1
         Loc
Treatment North South
     no1   35.3  25.9
     yes1  31.7  15.8
> m2
         Loc
Treatment North South
     no2    9.5   7.4
     yes2   9.6   4.0
```

But if I append them with `rbind`:

```
> rbind(m1,m2)
     North South
no1   35.3  25.9
yes1  31.7  15.8
no2    9.5   7.4
yes2   9.6   4.0
```

I've lost the "Treatment" and "Loc" names on the row and column dimensions.

**Is there a straightforward way to append the two without losing the dimnames?**

It's okay in this case to either assume the dimnames are the same, or to assume we simply want whatever dimnames the first object has.

Comment: Relevant answer as a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213468/r-losing-names-of-dimnames-of-a-table-after-cbind-or-rbind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
out <- rbind(m1,m2)
names(dimnames(out)) <- names(dimnames(m1))

#         Loc
#Treatment North South
#     no1   35.3  25.9
#     yes1  31.7  15.8
#     no2    9.5   7.4
#     yes2   9.6   4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice. I'd got as far as using `names(dimnames())` on the right to pull the names out, but it hadn't occurred to me that I might be able to assign to `names(dimnames())` on the left (even though I know I could do it with say `dimnames` alone).

Comment: @Glen_b - I didn't think it would work to be honest. Try it and see is my philosophy.

Comment: @thela, if you think any other programer uses some other philosophy, you probably going to be surprised...

Answer (score 3):

One thing that comes to mind is to use `melt` from "reshape2" and `xtabs`:

```
library(reshape2)
xtabs(value ~ Treatment + Loc, rbind(melt(m1), melt(m2)))
#          Loc
# Treatment North South
#      no1   35.3  25.9
#      yes1  31.7  15.8
#      no2    9.5   7.4
#      yes2   9.6   4.0
```

But a more efficient solution might be to just write a function that uses `rbind` makes use of the `dimnames` to get the result you want. Such a function might look like:

```
myFun <- function(...) {
  Lst <- list(...)
  Bound <- do.call(rbind, Lst)
  names(dimnames(Bound)) <- names(dimnames(Lst[[1]]))
  Bound
}
```

This takes the `names` of the `dimnames` from the first matrix and assigns it to the `names` of the `dimnames` of the bound set of matrices.

The `xtabs` solution also has the potential shortcoming that if there are duplicated `dimnames` in your matrices (for example, duplicated `rownames`), `xtabs` would `sum` those values. Compare the output, for instance, the difference in the results of the following:

```
xtabs(value ~ Treatment + Loc, rbind(melt(m1), melt(m2), melt(m2)))
myFun(m1, m2, m2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `melt`/`xtabs`, the nice function, the additional discussion at the end, and your pointer to the discussion in the R Public chatroom.